# When generating JavaDocs during a Maven Site Deploy, a MalformedInputException error is thrown

Tags: java, maven

The organization I work in uses a RAML tool as a way of building API documentation.  This documentation is included with the JavaDocs as an additional resource that makes up a full Maven site for our customers.

During the process of generating JavaDocs, the following error is encountered while doing a Yaml Merge of documentation:

```
java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

While the Maven build is successful, the RAML generator that follows fails because the API fails to generate its index file (api.html).

I realize that this question is somewhat broad, and that there are several ways to built site documentation.  Without worrying to much about the specifics, I am looking for possible causes of the original issue; what are common causes of the java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException?

It appears that character encoding could be the culprit, but I have already looked for incompatible characters (UTF-8 / Unicode character sets) in my recent commits, such as curly quotation marks (smart quotes), apostrophe symbols.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my own problem.  It took some time, since the error was quite cryptic.  But it gave me enough information.  The 'charset' portion of the package name indicated that an unsupported character might be present.

**SOLUTION**: A single smart apostrophe (unicode character) made it into a JavaDoc comment, which broken the process when the Yaml Merge was being ran as part of the Maven Site build.

[ ’ ] instead of [ ' ] was the culprit.  *That was a very expensive character!*